# Passar valor de um DialogFragment para o Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho o fragment1 e a DatePickerFragment

No caso `DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment`

Gostaria que ao selecionar a data retornasse para o fragment.

Só que está dando isso aqui:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Fragment.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
```

O método de recuperação é esse:

No `DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment`

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
        //...
        SimpleDateFormat data_br = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
        String data = data_br.format( date );
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra( "selectedDate",data );
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult( getTargetRequestCode(), 2, i );

}
```

E no onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i("RequestCode",""+requestCode);
        if( requestCode == 1 ){

        }

    }
```

Como faço para retornar o valor selecionado no DialogFragment para o fragmento ?

Answer (score 1):

Implemente no seu `Fragment` o `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`. Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

Sendo assim, será necessário incluir o método `onDateSet` sem precisar usar o `onActivityResult`. O resultado final seria:

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // aqui você resgata o ano, mês, dia etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem a certeza que isso funciona?

Comment: @ramaral aqui comigo funciona em uma Activity. Não testei com Fragment. Na minha cabeça segue mesma lógica. Vou testar mais tarde e confirmo aqui.

Comment: Perguntei porque não estou a ver como o DatePickerDialog sabe que esse método foi implementado no ArticleFragment.

Comment: Testei e testei e consegui chamando o DatePickerFragment dentro do próprio fragment, ai no onDateSet e apenas setei o valor que eu quis, ai funcionou

Comment: @adventistaam como o Ramaral questionou, eu estava testando aqui em um Fragment. Porque na verdade eu tinha feito apenas em uma Activity. Eu já estava a editar a pergunta

Comment: Beleza então! Estou começando nessa área de comunicação entre fragments

Comment: Como o AP diz que funcionou foi procurar como o DatePickerDialog teria conhecimento do *listener*. Ele é informado no construtor: `DatePickerDialog(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`.